# About standard bubble solutions for elliptic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

It is known that the problem
$
-\Delta u = u^p$  in  $\mathbb{R}^n
$
(which is known as Lane-Emden equation) has a positive solution of the form
$$
u(x)=\dfrac{c_n}{(1+|x|^2)^{(n-2)/2}}
$$
where $\Delta u=div(\nabla u)$ is the Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^n$,
$n > 2$ and $p= 2^* − 1 = \frac{n-2}{n+2}$, being $2^*$ the critical Sobolev exponent. The function $$  is called *standard bubble* in the elliptic theory of PDEs.

It is also known that there are others "bubble" solutions for different equations, for example
$$
-\Delta u + u = u^p \quad \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n,
$$
or
$$
(-\Delta)^2u = u^p \quad \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n,
$$
where $(-\Delta u)^2$ in the bi-Laplacian operator and $p$ is some special exponent.

Now I am interested in finding a bubble solution to the equations
$$
\Delta u + u= u^\alpha \quad \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n
$$
or
$$
\Delta u = u^\alpha \quad \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n
$$
with **$\alpha\in (0,1)$**. Note that I am taking $\Delta$ instead of $-\Delta$.

Do you know any paper where some of these equations (or similar) are studied? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought it was called the "Yamabe equation", but it is not at all important. I remember that I took a course on these things given by Emmanuel Hebey, he has at least a book on the subject, you can try having a look. However, I think that the standard resources are the books of Gilbarg-Trudinger and the one of Thierry Aubin.

Comment: Thanks, @GiuseppeNegro. I've checked those books but they all deal with an exponent greater than 1.  I think you are right about the name. When the exponent is critical the first equation is called the Yamabe equation.